# Windows 10 LyX 2.3.1 won't compile with hebrew in its path

Tags: lyx, windows, hebrew

The file runs fine on the desktop but fails to run when the path contains hebrew characters. This didn't happen with version 2.2. Below is the complete log file. It contains a few "!undefined control sequence \hebHEBREWLETTER" (HEBREWLETTER = vav, resh, shin etc.) or "! LaTeX Error: Command \hebHEBREWLETTER unavailable in encoding T1". Nothing seems to work. It's very frustrating. Does anyone have a solution?

I downloaded and installed culmus and cua_heb and set everything as instructed by various sites.

Comment: Can't you use the obvious solution to use a path without hebrew?

Comment: Of course, one solution (which is very annoying) is to rename all the folders and files in the path using english fonts). But it seems strange and quite impossible that LyX 2.3 cannot handle what 2.2 did without any extra definitions.

Comment: It seems that only the folder names create a problem. File names with Hebrew letters do not seem to affect anything. Very strange.

Comment: If I should guess I would say that the source of the problem is that latex now activates utf8 already in the format and lyx didn't adjust completly to it. Make a bug report in the lyx bug tracker.